# How to fix overflow of a dropdown?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I've 3 dropdowns. The options are coming well for the first dropdowns but the options for the last dropdown is kind of messy.

[image]

Here is my css

```
 select option {
        background: #E6EABF;
        color: #000000;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        z-index: 100;

 }
```

Please the last one is a multi-select dropdown.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: first i think add this `select option {-webkit-appearance: none;}`

Comment: Well, this is what multiple selection dropdowns look like. You'll need something else. (try using checkboxes, perhaps, or select2)

Comment: @Ylama I tried that but no luck :(

Comment: @Phiter So you are saying there is no other way? :O

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve. A select tag with multiple looks like this. It's not a dropdown, but a list.

Comment: look at this should do it --> https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri

Comment: I want to see all the options just like the above one and also select multiple options out of it..what would you suggest here? @Phiter

Comment: give the `select` an height?

Comment: In this case, try adding `height: auto;` to the select.

Comment: @Zeus07 look at my awnser just give the select an `size` property.

Comment: @Phiter I tried with _height: auto_ too but still the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

Give the select an `size` would have worked: `size="8"`

Since its not hard coded use `js`:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');
select.size = select.length;
```

```css
 
 select option {
        background: #E6EABF;
        color: #000000;
     
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" multiple size="return this.length();">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My Options varies from depending upon the option selected on the previous two dropdowns so I cannot hard code a random number.

Comment: @Zeus07 i see , so how do you generate the number , using php ? becuase then you can add the number into the size box as selected using some php code

Comment: I've scriplets through

Comment: so everything is oky you just want the styling better?? or also always display all the select option even if its more than 2? thing is somewhere something is adding to the multiple select and that i cant think its "scriplets"

Comment: Yes, just the styling. I want the users to all the options clearly not just through that tiny window. I've javascript and scriplets working together.